# how to locate in disk datapackages with persistent data when using bw_processing

Tags: brightway

If I create a datapackage with persistent data to reuse later something like

```
import bw_processing as bwp
from fs.zipfs import ZipFS

dp = bwp.create_datapackage()
dp.add_persistent_array(matrix=
'technosphere_matrix',indices_array=i_array,data_array=data_array,name='bananas')
```

I think I can recover it if I know where it is stored with

```
bwp.load_datapackage(ZipFS("some-path.zip"))
```

but how do I know this path ? I was hoping it was in dp.metadata but it seems is not